# I'm stuck on writing an implication statement in mathematical logic form.

Tags: real-analysis, logic

So I want to prove the statement "if the square of a number is an even integer, then the original number must also be an even integer". I'm thinking of using a proof by contradiction for this, but before I even start, I don't even know if my logical representation is correct.

This is what I have written down:
$(\forall a^2\in \mathbb{Z} : a^2=2m, m\in \mathbb{Z}) \Rightarrow (\forall a\in \mathbb{Z} : a=2n, n\in \mathbb{Z})$.

I know this isn't correct, but I definitely don't know how to write the correct one. Would anyone be able to provide me some pointers on the right answer, or even the actual answer? Also for the contradiction proof I will use, I have no clue how to negate the statement, so some pointers on that would be appreciated too.

PS: Sorry if my maths typesetting is wrong, this is my first time using it!

Cheers

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to _logically_ represent this? It can be very easily written down with words and some symbols.

Comment: Hi, yep - I really want to practice writing out statements in logic. Im starting real analysis in 3 weeks and I want to know some of the important stuff before I start.

Comment: Hello, $\forall a\in \mathbb{Z} \; (\exists m\in \mathbb{Z} , a^2=2m  \Rightarrow \exists n\in \mathbb{Z} , a=2n )$

Comment: The contraposition of ($A \Rightarrow B$) is ($\neg B \Rightarrow \neg A$).

Comment: @Mateo_13 Thanks for that, that makes a whole lot of sense now! How would I negate that statement?

Comment: $\neg (A \Rightarrow B)$ is ($A \wedge \neg B$)

Comment: You have everything you need to demonstrate the statement, try doing it and I'll correct it if necessary.